# Is there a way to find if a public IP address is from a resource in my aws account

Tags: amazon-web-services

I found an IP address when I look up the location of the IP address It show it is an Amazon IP. I there an way to find if that specific IP is from my account and which resources is using it?

Answer (score 0):

AWS [publish a list of IP ranges](https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json) which will be the best way to make it easier to find the resource with this attached to it.

If you can find the matching resource range for the IP within this file you can filter the specific service/region for the resources that are available.

Be aware that many services won't used fixed public IP addresses, which is why you're given a specific hostname instead to resolve.

If you're not familiar with CIDR notation take a look at [cidr.xyz](https://cidr.xyz/), by passing a CIDR in you should get the entire range of IP addresses that it covers.